# onfocus not being triggered when programmatically calling focus()

Tags: javascript

The problem I have is if I click on a link or tab to it onfocus is triggered but if I call focus() on the link programmatically it does NOT get called.

Here's some code I used to test. Notice how after the timeout runs focus is called on both links and the consoles aren't triggered but if you tab to them or click on them they do.

Is this just how it works and there is no way for me to get onfocus triggered when calling focus programmatically or am I missing something?

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onfocus = function () {
    console.log("link1 onfocus triggered")
};
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].onfocus = function () {
    console.log("link2 onfocus triggered")
};
window.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("timeout complete");
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].focus();
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].focus();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<a href="#">link1</a>
<a href="#">link2</a>
```

Comment: It does trigger for me... Chrome 46 on Win. Fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/58r6mg0h/ Try `addEventListener` instead of `on` property. Maybe there's a difference.

Comment: Hmm, works for me in Chrome and IE9 but not FF 41.0.2 which is where I was doing my testing. I tested mine in Chrome and IE and it worked there as well so it looks like it might be a FF specific issue.

Comment: Must be some sort of bug with FF, looks like you can't focus anything on the document, until the document has gotten some sort of focus.

Answer (score 0):

You've created custom functions `.onfocus` but you're calling `.focus()`?

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("timeout complete");
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onfocus();
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1].onfocus();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I'm trying to have the onfocus function called when focus occurs on the links. If I click/tab to the links my onfocus is called as expected. If I call focus on them directly it doesn't.

Comment: I misunderstood you actually. You were saying I created custom onfocus functions but that's not actually the case. onfocus is a function you can tie into whenever the links get focus. In my example if you click/tab to the links my onfocus is called because the links get focus. If I call focus on them directly though it doesn't.